# google drive developer account

Tags: google-drive-api

My application has a document management module and i want to use Google Drive for this.

Does Google allow me to create a Google Drive account and use my account in my personal application?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see https://developers.google.com/drive/

Comment: thanks for your reply. but there will be only one google drive account for all users. google really allows this.

Comment: I think, you will need to use this *one* Google Account for the Google drive authentication. And then handle the rest via permissions / settings / sharing to other Google accounts, if that's what you have in mind. By default, only one user can be assigned to one Google Drive account, but you can probably use the workaround via sharing (automated on your app logic side I suppose).